# Add noscroll class to body on menu click

Tags: javascript, wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm using underscores as a starter theme for Wordpress, and I'd like to add a 'noscroll' class to the body element when the menu button is toggled open, then remove it again when the menu is closed.

I've tried adding this kind of thing...

`$('body').addClass('noscroll');`

...to the existing navigation.js file that comes with underscores. Which looks like this...

https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/js/navigation.js

...but I just can't seem to find the right solution. Any help would be gratefully received and learnt from!

Comment: Have you tried `$("body").css('overflow', 'hidden')`? Its a one-liner and it should accomplish the same result. Set it back to 'auto' to unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend altering the navigation.js file as this some sort of pre-existing code that is not specific to your site.

What you can do is try enqueueing your custom script in your theme functions.php file like so:

```
function wpse39838169_addNoScroll() { ?>
<script>
$(".MENUBUTTONCLASS").on("click", function(e) {
    $('body').addClass('noscroll');
});
</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse39838169_addNoScroll');
```

Replace "MENUBUTTONCLASS" with the class of the button that will be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Spartacus, you set me on the right track. I did some testing and found that the following code added/removed the 'noscroll' class to the body when the button was clicked...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
      $('body').toggleClass('noscroll');
    });
});
```

...and I enqueued the the above code in the Wordpress functions.php file using an external javascript file in the normal way.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out!